# System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found

Tags: asp.net, http, authentication, axios, asp.net-identity

I am working on a project using ASP.net core with cookie authentication at back end, and front end is using reactjs with axios.

I had a problem that I can login succesfully, but I could not make any API call with [Authorize] property, the exception is :" System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found"

I debugged into ASP.net UseExceptionHandler, I can see the cookie is indeed sent from front end in the header.

Please help.

Sever side code:
In ConfigServices

```
services.AddIdentityCore<UserEntity>(config =>
            {
                //  Require a confirmed email in order to log in
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            })
                .AddRoles<RoleEntity>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<LmsApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddSignInManager()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie();
```

In Configure:

```
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions { 
               HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.None,
            });
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
```

Login Code:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserLoginResult>> Login(UserLoginModel userLogin)
        {
            if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(HttpContext.User))
                await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            
            SignInResult ret = null;

            try
            {
                var user = await userManager.Users.Where(c => c.UserName == userName).Include(u => u.Roles).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                ret = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, userLogin.Password, userLogin.RememberMe, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                lmsCore.Logger.Error(e.Message);
            }

            if (ret?.Succeeded ?? false)
            {
                return Ok(new UserLoginResult
                {
                    UserId = user.Id
                };
            }
            else if (ret?.IsLockedOut ?? false)
                throw new UiFriendlyException(lmsCore, ConstErrorCode.USER_ACCOUNT_LOCKED);
            

             throw new UiFriendlyException(lmsCore, ConstErrorCode.USER_PASSWORD_NOT_MATCH);
}
```

Exception details are below:

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

FIX BELOW:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<UserLoginResult>> Login(UserLoginModel userLogin)
        {
            if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            
            SignInResult ret = await signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, userLogin.Password, (user.TenantId != null || user.NormalizedName != "ADMIN")); ;

            if (ret.Succeeded)
            {
                var claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString())
                };
                var authProperteis = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),
                };

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), authProperteis);
    }
    return Ok(true);
}
```

Comment: After debugging for hours, I realized that the cookies is indeed attached by axios, and server received too. Just an exception has occur, the exception information is added to question, please help:

Comment: The problem seems to be that Login function is not happy with SignInManager. I have attached the fixed code at the end in case someone has same problem.